# Apache will not start using mod_ssl.so

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, openssl

Using centos 4.4/apache 2.2.13 with openssl 0.9.8k Built from source.

Getting message below, on startup. Everything seems to build fine
mod_ssl.so: undefined sysmbol: SSL_CTX_set_info_callback

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, its a problem with openssl, I got it to work with openssl-0.9.7m, most of the 0.9.8 releases did not work.As long as the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to something like LD_LIBRARY_PATH=usr/local/lib (because thats where libcryto and susch files are)

So when as long as openssl is working correctly, apache can mod_ssl can be used against 0.9.7m for mod_ssl. strange as there were many people with the same problem and no answer.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's in the ldconfig cache ?
You can see it using ldconfig -p. Example :

```
ldconfig -p | egrep -i '(ssl|crypt)'
```

Be sure to have your openssl 0.9.8k build.

If not, update your /etc/ld.so.conf (or /etc/ld.so.conf/openssl.conf - I don't know how CentOS is organized). Then run ldconfig again, to update its cache.